# Objective-C get email addresses from string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSString containing several email addresses and some other random text. I would like to be able to pull out just the email addresses. They all have the same domain, say @business.com, for example. What would be the best approach to this?

Sample string (HTML)

```
            <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#000000">
        <p align="center"><b><font color="#FFFFFF" size="2">title</font></b></p></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td valign="top">

<font size="2"><b>lastname</b>, firstname A.,&nbsp;name@business.com</font><br>

<font size="2"><b>lastname</b>, firstname A.,&nbsp;name@business.com</font><br>

<font size="2"><b>lastname</b>, firstname,&nbsp;name@business.com</font><br>

<font size="2"><b>lastname</b>, firstname,&nbsp;name@business.com</font><br>
```

Comment: Are the addresses delimited?  Basically, I'm looking for a pattern.  Chance are, you may be able to use the `comonentsSeparatedByString:` method of the `NSString` object.

Comment: No, they are part of a results string that lists Name, position, email etc. separated only by line break

Comment: provide a sample result.  As Alex suggests in the answer, you may be able to take advantage of regular expressions.

Comment: Does your string include the html markup?  Or you just trying to get fancy? :D

Comment: Yes, it does. The string is actually the source code from a WebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of creating an example for you since I was interested myself:

```
NSString *someHTML = @"<b>lastname</b>, firstname,&nbsp;test1@business.com</font><b>lastname</b>, firstname,&nbsp;test2@business.com</font><b>lastname</b>, firstname,&nbsp;test3@business.com</font>";
NSRegularExpression *regex   = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\w*@business.com)" options: NSRegularExpressionUseUnixLineSeparators error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:someHTML options:NSMatchingWithTransparentBounds range:NSMakeRange(0, someHTML.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in matches)
{
    NSString *email = [someHTML substringWithRange:[result range]];
    NSLog(email);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with a pattern that [finds email addresses](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).